# NSString change format

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have a string

**120505**

The format is always as above. The content however may change. I want it to be:

**12-05-05**

How can I do that?

Comment: @ArpitParekh, For me seems like simple string manipulation. Are you sure NSDateFormatter will be able to handle "120505" as an input?

Comment: @tweetWithThisOwl_FollowMe : No you are right..I am sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 NSMutableString *editedstring = [NSMutableString stringWithString:yourstring];
 [editedstring insertString:@"-" atIndex:2];
 [editedstring insertString:@"-" atIndex:5];
```

This perfect for your requirements than after I suggest you to read following apple guideline because from that you can know more.

[NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i)

Comment: The only thing helps you the most is reading API, and you have proved it!

Answer (score 2):

Use this class method, for your reference

```
+(NSString *)getString:(NSInteger)pTemp
{
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:pTemp];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setGroupingSize:2];
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"-"];
    [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
    NSString *finalString = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
    [formatter release];
    return finalString;
}
```

Change this method according to your requirement, and It will help you for strings greater then 6 characters.

Once again this function is for your reference only dear.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the input string as an NSString variable named in_string, then you can use the snippet below to produce the output in a variable named out_string:

```
 NSString* out_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%@-%@", [in_string substringToIndex: 2], [in_string substringWithRange: NSRangeMake(2,2)], [in_string substringFromIndex: 4]];
```